# Code does not build succesfully when integrating Azure Push Notifications

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, bintray

My code worked fine until 2 days ago when it stopped building and started showing the following error.

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-generator/maven-metadata.xml'. 
Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

I found that the culprit is the following line of code in the 'repositories' section of build.gradle file.

```
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK" }
```

If i remove this line, the build is successful again. I have tried opening this url in browser and it gives **502 bad gateway** error. I have heard that bintray will stop working , but i am not sure. Incase its true, i could not find any replacement of this line in the Azure Sdk Integration document.

Can someone please help resolving this issue. Thank you